# Too many active sessions - cannot install apps from Play Store anymore

Tags: google-play-store, crashes

PlayStore crashes each time I try to install/update an app since a few days. I have an unmodified Honor 7.
I found the resulting stacktrace:

```
... 30147-30147/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.android.vending, PID: 30147
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many active sessions for UID 10029
                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1551)
                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1496)
                                                       at android.content.pm.IPackageInstaller$Stub$Proxy.createSession(IPackageInstaller.java:247)
                                                       at android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.createSession(PackageInstaller.java:297)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.installer.PackageInstallerImpl.innerCreateSession(PackageInstallerImpl.java:145)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.installer.PackageInstallerImpl.createSession(PackageInstallerImpl.java:94)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.receivers.InstallerImpl.requestInstall(InstallerImpl.java:410)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.LightPurchaseFlowActivity.acquire(LightPurchaseFlowActivity.java:648)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.LightPurchaseFlowActivity.access$800(LightPurchaseFlowActivity.java:22929)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.LightPurchaseFlowActivity$4.run(LightPurchaseFlowActivity.java:837)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Tracing the UID with help of ADB to the package *com.android.vending* which is the PlayStore.

So far without success:
- clearing cache
- clearing data
- Deleting/Adding Google account

Comment: Further unsuccessful tries:
- downgrading PlayStore and afterwards installing latest APK
- deactivate/activate

Answer (score 0):

Yay. Works again. I tried again to downgrade PlayStore (= deactivate/uninstall all updates). Afterwards no success. But after a shutdown + following boot the store is able to install&update apps again... Strange.

Comment: Was that the first time you tried restarting the phone?

Comment: No. Did this previously. But cannot remember if I did this after downgrading PlayStore before. Presumably not...